# removeのエラーについて

Tags: python

プログラミングの課題をしていた時、このようなエラーが出てしましました。

bはinputでリスト内の数字を入力したのですが、その数字が削除されず、逆にエラーが出てしました。何を変えても同じようなエラーばかり出て、どうにもできません。原因とどうすればいいか教えてくださると嬉しいです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-abee044cc51a> in <module>()
     25 if b in numbers:
     26   print(str(b)+"を削除します")
---> 27   numbers.remove(b)
     28 if b not in numbers:
     29   print(str(b)+"はありません")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Comment: numbers、bはどういう値ですか？

Comment: numbers=[110,111,112]
b=111で設定しました！

Comment: `'str' object has no ...` と表示されていますので、`numbers` が文字列になっているのでしょう(`"[110,111,112]"`)。また、`input()` で入力した `111` も文字列で int 型に変換していないため、`if b in numbers: ...` が部分文字列の判定になっているものと推察します。

Comment: つまりnumbersとbをint型にすれば良いということですか？

Comment: @students その通りですが、numbers は int のリストにします(`numbers = [110, 111, 112]`)。

Comment: おかげさまでできました！！ありがとうございます！

Comment: 自己解決の形で構いませんので、お時間のある時にでも回答欄にご自身がやってみて上手くいった方法をまとめて質問を閉じてください。